# Что выдаёт линукс?

Tags: java

Если я проверяю ОС с помощью оператора

```
System.out.println((System.getProperty("os.name"));
```

я получаю ответ  - Windows 7
Подскажите, как узнать, что вернёт этот оператор на других системах (линукс, Windows10, MacOS)
Мне нужно в зависимости от системы установить разный размер Frame, но у меня нет возможности попробовать этот оператор на всех этих системах

Comment: У вас есть возможность попробовать всё что угодно в виртуальных машинах

Comment: Не пробовал, их установить сложно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку [SystemUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html)

Там можно проверить не только по ОС, но и по их версиям

```
IS_OS_LINUX
IS_OS_MAC
IS_OS_WINDOWS
```